# A docker image for interactive use, with more utilities?

Tags: docker

Often when looking at new software, I like to install it in a docker container and try it out before I commit to either

1. Writing a proper Dockerfile for it, or
2. Trying it out on my host

So I open up a brand new container using `docker run --rm -it debian bash` and then I find myself installing a bunch of basic utilities like `wget` and doing apt-updates.

I figure that this might be a common use case. Are there any docker images which are suited for this, before I decide to roll out my own?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to create your own image with all configurations you want. The process is create your folder images configurations:

```sh
mkdir myimage
```

The create your Dockerfile with the following command:

```sh
vi myimage/Dockerfile`
```

Add this into your file:

```sh
#Your comments about
FROM ubuntu:16.04
LABEL author="William Ventura user@foo.com"
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y wget 
#RUN apt-get install -y package1 package2
#EXPOSE 80
```

Then you have have to create your own image with your configurations you did in the `Dockerfile` with the following command:

```sh
docker build -f myimage/Dockerfile -t user/myimage .
```

And it is going to build your own image where you will have installed all the packages you defined in the file.

The you will be able to create containers as you usually do:

```sh
docker exec -it --name myimage user/myimage bash
```

Finally you will have `myimage` with the tools built-in.